# Como otimizar a inicialização no Elementary OS com o Stacer ou terminal: o que posso tirar?

Tags: boot

boa noite. Sou novo aqui e novo no Linux e estou maravilhado com o Elementary OS 5.1 (Hera). Já deveria ter migrado anos antes. Nunca mais Windows.

Como estou estudando sozinho, instalei o Stacer para aumentar a velocidade da inicialização, fiz alguns testes retirando algumas coisas e não adiantou, quase tenho que formatar, como muito sacrifício e pesquisa consegui reativar. **Retirei inicialmente o NetworkManager-wait-online.service e não prestou**, não consegui acessar a rede de forma alguma depois e parece que outros apps dependem dele. Ficou horrível, mas corrigi. **Depois retirei o avahi-daemon e trouxe de volta.**

Gente, por favor, para evitar que eu faça maiores pepinos, fiz 08 prints com o que o Stacer mostra no startup, e do terminal. Se possível, **me ajudem por favor com o que retirar no STARTUP do STACER ou pelo TERMINAL para melhorar a inicialização**. Me parece que não dá para anexar tudo. Então segue abaixo o do terminal e em anexo os prints do Stacer com o link, mas não sei se saiu certo o link das imagens, são 8:

**Com o systemd-analyze:**

Startup finished in 3.454s (firmware) + 5.619s (loader) + 5.303s (kernel) + 1min 27.852s (userspace) = 1min 42.228s
graphical.target reached after 37.333s in userspace

**Com o systemd-analyze blame, os primeiros 50:**

```
     53.487s apt-daily.service
     18.240s dev-sda2.device
      8.495s dev-loop5.device
      7.702s dev-loop14.device
      7.626s snapd.service
      7.518s dev-loop13.device
      7.136s dev-loop12.device
      6.731s dev-loop11.device
      6.439s dev-loop9.device
      6.217s dev-loop7.device
      6.106s dev-loop10.device
      6.106s dev-loop8.device
      6.106s dev-loop4.device
      6.106s dev-loop0.device
      6.105s dev-loop6.device
      6.105s dev-loop3.device
      5.332s ufw.service
      4.229s dev-loop2.device
      4.195s dev-loop1.device
      3.985s systemd-udevd.service
      3.167s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-FEBE\x2dEA7F.service
      2.908s udisks2.service
      2.693s networkd-dispatcher.service
      2.676s ModemManager.service
      2.643s grub-common.service
      2.629s lvm2-monitor.service
      2.463s accounts-daemon.service
      2.356s gpu-manager.service
      1.825s alsa-restore.service
      1.825s systemd-logind.service
      1.823s speech-dispatcher.service
      1.818s lm-sensors.service
      1.817s avahi-daemon.service
      1.813s thermald.service
      1.812s rsyslog.service
      1.804s pppd-dns.service
      1.801s nvidia-persistenced.service
      1.790s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.785s NetworkManager.service
      1.283s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.134s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.118s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      1.079s snap-nmap-2254.mount
      1.078s snap-libreoffice-204.mount
      1.077s snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d5\x2dstable-16.mount
      1.002s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount
       938ms systemd-sysctl.service
       935ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime-216.mount
       848ms snap-whatsdesk-20.mount
       847ms snap-snapd-11036.mount
```

**Com o systemd-analyze critical-chain:**

The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @37.333s[image]
└─multi-user.target @37.333s
└─snapd.seeded.service @37.288s +44ms
└─snapd.service @29.658s +7.626s
└─basic.target @29.643s
└─sockets.target @29.643s
└─snapd.socket @29.641s +1ms
└─sysinit.target @29.579s
└─systemd-timesyncd.service @29.467s +110ms
└─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @28.688s +756ms
└─local-fs.target @28.684s
└─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 2.417s
└─run-user-1000.mount @1min 1.647s
└─local-fs-pre.target @7.114s
└─lvm2-monitor.service @4.485s +2.629s
└─lvm2-lvmetad.service @6.468s
└─lvm2-lvmetad.socket @4.484s
└─system.slice @4.372s
└─-.slice @4.294s

Agradeço imensamente e peço desculpas antecipadas pelo texto grande e pelo abuso. Grande Abraço.

Comment: Desculpa pela digitação errada "fiz alguns testes"

Comment: English, please.